# 2d slice cut of tetrahedral mesh in tecplot 360 ex

Tags: visualization, plotting

I have made a 2d slice cut of a 3 dimension figure. When I select "mesh" to display the mesh on the slice, tecplot seems to connect the vertices in a strange way (it seems like two 2d meshes are superimposed). I found a similar question in the forum of tecplot but they did not answer it.

Edit:
Here is a capture of the 2d slice cut

[image]

Comment: Maybe a figure would help us ?

Comment: This question seem as off-topic to me. Also, I think that you can improve the figure, e.g., adding the original 3D mesh and the plane that is cutting it. The manual of Tecplot does not say what is the algorithm they use for the slices. It might be possible that this is the common behavior.

Comment: @nicoguaro it seems to me that the question could be expressed as "how to visualize a cut of a 3D mesh". It is in my opinion a relevant question for simulation scientists. Would it solve the "off-topic" problem?

Comment: @BertrandGazanion, if that's the question it should be reflected in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the image, what you see is the intersection between a plane and the tetrahedra. Slicing tetrahedra generates new polygons, for instance, it can generate quadrilaterals (there is one on the bottom of your image). See also the right attached image.

If you want to visualize the mesh, it may be better to display the tetrahedra that "straddle" the clipping plane, as on the left attached image.

The images were generated with geobox/vorpaview, both part of my open-source [geogram software http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html](http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html).

[image: two slicing mode for visualizing tetrahedral grids. Left: straddling cells; right: slicing]

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to obtain the equivalent of your left figure with Tecplot ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Tecplot. By googling around, I have seen a post that mentions a "Clip option": http://tecplottalk.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1815 maybe it has what you need (just guessing...)

Comment: Yes, the advice from the tecplot guys gives exactly the figure I have included in my question, i.e. the equivalent of your right figure. I guess obtaining something like your left figure is not directly feasible in tecplot.

Comment: It's weird, because from a programming point of view it is much easier, so I'd be surprised if tecplot developers did not include the option (but I have no idea of how to activate it in tecplot, sorry)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. And from what I have seen, it seems complicated to obtain a clear answer on their forum  about what tecplot can or can not do (hence my question here).